# beep() function in C++ "was not declared in scope"

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use C++ `beep()` function of windows.h in CDT. But it doesn't compile and throws this error:

> 'beep' was not declared in this scope
>    Function 'beep' could not be
>   resolved
>   Here is the code:

```
/*
 * blahblah.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 28, 2016
 *      
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    beep(523, 500);

    //cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MinGW on a 64 bit Win7 machine
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [`Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx)? It is case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `Beep` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) begins with a capital `B`. C++ is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Arghhhh! What a mistake! Seems like I'm real tired. Thanks!